# Within a firebase project, can I update values in the firestore database from the real time database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

There is an integer value in the my real time database that I'd like to have sync'd with an integer value in my firestore database. The realtime database is fed through an external source and when it gets an update, I'd like that pushed to the firestore database

Here's what I have so far, I am able to access the value in the realtime database but not the firestore database.

=============== Data Structure===================

Real Time database

```
user1:  
 { meter : 20 }

Firestore database

Collection: Users
   {Document : user1 
        { meter : 20 }}
```

/// =============Code Sample ======================================

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Initialize the Firebase application with admin credentials

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


// Define user sync method

exports.meterSync = functions.database.ref('/user1/meter').onUpdate( (change, context) => {

    // Get a reference to the Firestore document of the changed user
    var userDoc = admin.firestore().doc(`user/${context.params.user1}`);

    const meterReading = change.after.val();
    console.log(meterReading);

    console.log(userDoc); /// Not able to access this

    return null

});
```

My expectation is that user doc will give me the document, so I can update the fields within it. But I am getting a documentReference object, not sure how to access the meter field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing

```
var userDoc = admin.firestore().doc(`user/${context.params.user1}`);
```

You actually defined a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference).

You have to use this `DocumentReference` to write to the Firestore database, using the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) or [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) methods.

Here is a code using the `set()` method:

```
exports.meterSync = functions.database
  .ref('/{userId}/meter')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {

    const meterReading = change.after.val();
    console.log(meterReading);

    // Get a reference to the Firestore document of the changed user
    const userDoc = admin.firestore().doc(`user/${context.params.userId}`);

    return userDoc.set(
      {
        meter: meterReading
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, Renaud ! This helped with getting the update within the firestore db but it creates a new _undefined_ document within the _user_ collection as opposed to updating the _userID_ document. Do you know what could be missing ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "undefined document"? What is your exact data structure on the Firestore side and what is the exact record/node you update on the Realtime database side? You may fine tune the code depending on your exact requirements and your data structures.

Comment: ||||| Cloud Firestore:   **Collection :** _user_ -> **Document :** _userID_ -> **Field:** _meterReading_

||||| Realtime Database: _userID_ / _meterReading_

||||| When I use the code sample above, instead of updating the same cloud firestore **Document :** _userID_ , it created a new **Document :** _undefined_

Comment: Shouldn't it be |||||  RealtimeDatabase: userID / meter ||||| as in your question? If you get an undefined doc ID it is because `context.params.userId` is undefined. You should debug the code in your environment through console.logs, and possibly adapt it.

Comment: Yep, my mistake while typing, it is ||||| RealtimeDatabase: userID / meter ||||| ... I'll debug but what do you mean by context.params.userId is undefined ? Doesn't that point to the specific document ?

Comment: We are declaring the `userDoc` DocumentReference with `doc('user/${context.params.userId}')`. If this doc is under the `user` collection with an `undefined` document ID it means that `context.params.userId`value is `undefined`.

Comment: Note that the code in my answer was successfully tested. You might have a problem somewhere in either your data structure or something else.

Comment: Will test out data structure. But you're right, the code sample above was very helpful with the push of info from the realtime db to firestore db. Thank you !

Comment: you were right, the code was good, just a minor issue with the DocumentReference. Thanks ! Just to close this out, **Corrected DocumentReference: **  `const userDoc = admin.firestore().collection('user').doc(userID);`

Comment: Fine! FYI, note that you could also do: `const userDoc = admin.firestore().doc('user/' + userID);`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use cloud functions for this, lets say, you have one background function:

```
export const one = functions.firestore.document('users').onWrite((change, context) => {
      // ... Your code here
})

export const two = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    // ... you code here
})
```

Since you have access to the firebase sdk admin in there you basically can achieve your goal. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)